# Can an aboleth establish a mental link with targets it can't see?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, telepathy

So, imagine an aboleth, living in its lair as the party enters it. Without resorting to other means of detecting them, can it use its telepathy to speak to the party no matter where they are, so long as they are in range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless otherwise stated a monster, in this case an aboleth, doesn't need to be able to see the creature(s) it wishes to communicate telepathically with. However, it should be noted that the aboleth can only telepathically communicate with *one* creature at a time.

From page 9 of the Monster Manual:

> **A telepathic monster doesn't need to see a contacted creature** and can end the telepathic contact at any time. The contact is broken as soon as the two creatures are no longer within range of each other or if the telepathic monster contacts a different creature within range.